# How to establish a bi directional connection with ssl certificate?

Tags: web-services, security, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to connect with one of my client to call api methods from their server, the client want to have a bi-directional commnunication, they shared their security certificate which contains CACert.crt, another file with .crt, .key, .p7b, .pfx files. Now They want us to share our certificate. I've following questions:

1. How I install their certificate?
2. How I can generate my certificate? Do I need to purchase certificate for this or I need to generate something based on their certificate?
3. They mentioned about DataPower public certificate. After Googling, I found Datapower is from the IBM, can I create a free certificate from it?

I'm absolutely new to this, tried to google a lot, but couldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your client wants you to use [a client certificate](https://gist.github.com/mtigas/952344). They've provided you with a CA for you to use; just use that to fulfill the signing request for the certificate you generate.